# Android getString performance issue in adapter holder

Tags: android, getstring

I access string resource in adapter. But I have a concern Which way to be usefull or better performance? First way seems like not usefull but does it create problems in terms of performance?

**1;**

```
Context context;
public Adapter(Context context){
     this.context = context;
}

...
...

public void onBind(Holder holder,int position) {
     holder.text.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.formText, position));
}
```

**2;**

```
Context context;
String formText;

public Adapter(Context context){
     this.context = context;
     this.formText= context.getResources().getString(R.string.formText);
}

...
...

public void onBind(Holder holder,int position) {
     holder.text.setText(String.format(formText, position));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second has less a performance hit. You avoid the lookup of the string resource more than once. Without a proper benchmark, can't say how much performance is affected.

As far as usefulness, both will work.